# Missing PyGST Plugin?

Tags: python, gstreamer

I'm running python 2.6 and PyGST (most recent available for Python 2.6). I've installed all the plugins - good, bad, and ugly.

I have the following code:

```
import sys, os
import pygtk, gtk, gobject
import pygst
pygst.require("0.10")
import gst

class GTK_Main:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Audio-Player")
        window.set_default_size(300, -1)
        window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")
        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        window.add(vbox)
        self.entry = gtk.Entry()
        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, False, True)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Start")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.start_stop)
        vbox.add(self.button)
        window.show_all()

        self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin2", "player")
        fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
        self.player.set_property("video_sink", fakesink)
        bus = self.player.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message", self.on_message)

    def start_stop(self, w):
        if self.button.get_label() == "Start":
            filepath = self.entry.get_text()
            if os.path.isfile(filepath):
                self.button.set_label("Stop")
                self.player.set_property("uri", filepath)
                self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
            else:
                self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
                self.button.set_label("Start")

    def on_message(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == gst.MESSAGE_EOS:
            self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
            self.button.set_label("Start")
        elif t == gst.MESSAGE_ERROR:
            self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            print "Error: %s" % err, debug
            self.button.set_label("Start")

GTK_Main()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

However, when I run this module and try to open a file, I get the following error.

> Error: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
>   ..........\Source\gst-plugins-base\gst\playback\gsturidecodebin.c(991):
>   gen_source_element ():
>   /GstPlayBin2:player/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0

How do I correct this?

EDIT: The first answer works on Ubuntu, but it does not work on Windows. Bounty will be awarded to whoever solves the problem for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some research has shown that this is apparently an error in a DLL. Tweaks may need to be made to the source, and the source compiled, instead of using WinBuilds.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a full uri: 
if you handle only files on your local filesystem and want to insert the file path only, change the line

```
self.player.set_property("uri", filepath)
```

to something like this:

```
self.player.set_property("uri", "file://"+filepath)
```

AND: GST has some routines to handle uri better the just prepending `'file://'`.
[A good tutorial is here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html)

Comment: I changed the line, and the error message changed. Path: C:\Users\user\Downloads\Overcome.mp3. Error: Could not open resource for reading. ..\..\..\..\..\Source\gst-plugins-base\ext\gio\gstgiosrc.c(324): gst_gio_src_get_stream (): /GstPlayBin2:player/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstGioSrc:source:
Could not open location file:///C:/GTKTutorial/file:/C:/Users/user/Downloads/Overcome.mp3 for reading: Error opening file: Invalid argument

Comment: you mean you have entered the path: 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Overcome.mp3' and the error message says that the file at: file:///C:/GTKTutorial/file:/C:/Users/user/Downloads/Overcome.mp3 does not exist? Where does the first part of the path come from?

Comment: I do not know...I tried both ways, and the issue is still there.

Comment: could you replace the line with:
self.player.set_property("uri", "file://C:/Users/user/Downloads/Overcome.mp3")
and then click start?

Comment: No error, but absolutely no response. I confirmed that the file is there, and it does have audio. However, after clicking start, the program is not playing the file.

Comment: OK, the code with the change to a real uri works here. You could check if gst works. Run the following in a command line (if it does not play, then your problem is probably elsewhere): gst-launch-0.10 playbin uri=file://C:/Users/user/Downloads/Overcome.mp3

Comment: I ran that code, and playbin is "invalid syntax". Are you sure that code is correct?

Comment: I'm sure its the right syntax (on linux at least). It's from here: http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/introduction.html  Are you sure that you ran it on a command line (that means: NOT in python)?

Comment: @JasonMc92 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2334/discussion-between-xubuntix-and-jasonmc92)

Comment: This answer works on Ubuntu. Still unsure of the Windows solution.